# WSO2 AM 1.6: Publish service to cluster

Tags: api, wso2, cluster-computing

We create and publish a service through the web console (/publisher). This is environment is a 2 node WSO2 AM cluster with a loadbalancer on top of it (HAProxy).

When we invoke the service (SoapUI), via this load balancer, one request succeeds and the next one fails and so on.

IMHO: The cluster configuration should be correct. I can see the published service on both nodes if I start the /publisher app on each node.

```
axis2.xml:
- Hazelcast clustering is enabled
- Using multicast

master-datasources.xml
- pointing to Oracle database

api-manager/xml
- pointing to jdbc string in master-datasources.xml
```

Does anyone have some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Synapse Artifact is not deployed on two Gateways correctly. Can you go to /repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default/api and see if the both node have an xml file for the published API. If you haven't enabled Deployment Synchroniser the artifact will only be created in one node.

Comment: I changed the carbon.xml file. Here it describes the DeploymentSynchronizer. #happy